# payfast not redirecting to notify_url

Tags: payment-gateway

I am working with payfast integration in testing env. I have defined all required criteria like.

- merchant_id
- merchant_key
- amount
- item_name
- return_url
- cancel_url
- notify_url

**Problem:**   I have defined notify_url but payfast is not calling my notify_url. It's just calling my return url.

**Notify Url:**

- My notify_url is public accessible
- It's also responding 200 OK

But payfast is not redirecting to *notify_url* only redirecting to 'return_url'

Comment: It’s not supposed to _redirect_ there in the first place. Their _servers_ will make a request to that URL.

Comment: @CBroe - I have modified my question, 
payfast is not redirecting to notify_url only redirecting to 'return_url'

Comment: And how exactly have you verified that?

Comment: @CBroe - I tested with postman it's giving 200 OK

Comment: Start by checking your server logs to see if these requests actually reach your system.

Comment: Only return_url request is reaching,  notify_url request not reaching

Comment: Impossible to debug for us here, with the info you have given so far. I would suggest that you go check their documentation for trouble shooting tips or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe  - what extra information you want for help me

Comment: I don’t know this provider, so hard to tell which info would be necessary to properly debug it. Showing your code regarding the configuration variables, and what your notification script looks like could be a start. You should also implement some logging in your notification script (like make it append the current timestamp every time it is called to a text file), so that you can verify when it does get called more easily.

Comment: Below is code
<form action="https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10000100">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="46f0cd694581a">
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://test/return">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://test/cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://test/notify">

<button type="submit">SUbmit </button>

Answer (score 1):

When a successful payment is made, PayFast will send an ITN(Payment Confirmation) to your `notify_url`.

They will send the ITN to your `notify_url` **before** a user gets redirected to your `return_url`.

When the ITN gets sent to your `notify_url`, you will have to save the return variables in your database.

By doing this, when a user gets redirected to your `return_url`, you can source the information out of your database and update your system accordingly.

You will also have to ensure you're using the correct port as per their [documentation](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#itn-callback-errors).

Comment: As @Shepard_ZA said - you will not be redirected to the `notify_url`, only to the `return_url`. The 'getting started' section explains this -https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/

Comment: @Daniel_ZA  I am not understanding 
"PayFast makes use of ports 80, 8080, 8081 and 443 only." Do i have to redirect notify_url to http://myurl:8080/notify_url

Comment: @JAMES, if your `notify_url` is not making use of one of those 4 ports, then you would need to change it to use one of them or else you will not receive the ITN callback from PayFast

Comment: how to match signature returned from payfast with my parmameters on server in notify url in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing locally you will need to have a publicly accessible URL (notify_url) in order to receive the notifications, consider using tools such as NGROK or Expose to expose your local development server to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a tunneling service for making the notify URL publicly accessible, make sure that there isn't any redirects from the proxy provided by the tunneling service. Payfast will halt the notify request if it is redirected.